# How to make a GUI to display my game?

Tags: java, user-interface

I have already coded a game which is played on a 2D grid. Now I just need to make a GUI to display it.

Each cell in my grid has an attribute that goes along with an image. For instance, if cell (0, 0) is water, I want to display an image of water in that pixel. I have already made images for each attribute (e.g. image of a character, water, land, etc.). I just don't know how to make the GUI.

It's a simple 2d map where each pixel (cell) is a specific texture/character/item. I also would like the character to move around, that is it.

Any resources or help would be appreciated. I've tried searching for a tutorial but they all seem so complicated and use Color to fill in their map instead of images.

Thanks.

Comment: Start working with Java's Swing library to learn the basics.  You'll also need to implement a game loop with the Timer class, I believe, which should be covered in most Swing GUI game tutorials, example projects, books, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a 2D platformer that makes use of a simple thread, drawing, gamestates, etc. Although you might not need the full extent of everything it has, you might find interest in the main thread logic, etc. I believe he has a link to the source code in the comments. [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5pyv5qOAofI)